# Oracle syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i, ora-00933

I got the following error in Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM abcd WHERE name LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 10
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

What is the problem with the command?

Answer (score 15):

Oracle doesn't support the `limit` clause. That's a MySQL/Postgres thing.

There are alternatives, although they're often a lot more involved

http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html

The simplest equivalent is:

```
select * from abcd where name like 'a%' and ROWNUM <= 10;
```

Comment: then i want to limit the keywords to 10 for a specific search what should i do

Comment: Please be careful when limiting query results using <rownum in combination with an order by clause. You may not get the results you expect. Oracle first limits the number of rows and then does the sort.

Comment: @Rene: Indeed, it can bite you. In this case, though, it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: `LIMIT` is supported on MySQL and Postgres